# Applovin tvOS LIbrary Issues

Tags: xcode, swift, tvos, tvos9.1, applovin

I apologize but I am new to tvOS development, an programming in general.

**IDE:** Xcode 7.2.1
**language:** Swift 2
**platform:** tvOS

I am currently trying to integrate the AppLovin SDK for my tvOS app.

I have followed the documentation and have everything set up for Swift.

However, there is one glaring problem. when downloading the SDK the static library File:   *libAppLovinTVOS.a*  does not populate as a library.But rather a generic Document file.

I have downloaded it a couple times to see if it was just an error in downloading. Even tried to go to their gitHub to no avail. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

(sorry for breaking up the text it helps with my dyslexia)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of both your project file tree, and your "Link Binary with Libraries" pane in the Build Phases page of your .xcodeproj file?

Comment: @dokun  here are the images you requested  [link] (http://s292.photobucket.com/user/aknapp1212/media/Screen%20Shot%202016-03-11%20at%2012.58.24%20PM_zps9tgplyto.png.html)

Comment: Other than appearing as the wrong kind of file, is it causing any problem?  I see that you have it successfully included in your library list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when downloading the SDK the static library File: libAppLovinTVOS.a does not populate as a library.But rather a generic Document file.

**There's nothing wrong.** The file is a static library, not a framework, and it's completely normal for those to appear as plain old document files. I've got several similar libraries in my iOS project right now and they have exactly the same generic icon.

Comment: Yes. Are you having some kind of problem?

Comment: the ads aren't populating, but maybe it's deeper on my end then just implementation of Applovin. When I didn't see the extentison change to a library I thought that was the issue.  but I'll make a button an try it out, Thanks again

Comment: Sure, there are lots of reasons that you might not get ads. If you can build the app and use the classes and functions that the library provides without error, the library itself is fine.

Comment: I meant to response from before, You were right it worked fine!